# Extract substring from text using python

Tags: python, string, substring, extract

I have some values in a column that looks like this:

```
{"template":{"module":[{"id":"module-12","header":[{"id":"title","value":"Cycle in Comfort","decorators":[]}],"paragraph":[{"id":"description","value":["This folding exercise bike features a heavily-padded seat and backrest for your comfort."]
```

Is there any way I can extract information from it and paste it in other columns? Information that need to be extracted:

```
module-12
Cycle in Comfort
This folding exercise bike features a heavily-padded seat and backrest for your comfort
```

Any advice on extracting the needed information?

Answer (score 1):

assuming your dictionary object name `mydict` :

```
item = mydict["template"]['module'][0]
module_12 = item['id']
header = item['header'][0]
cycle = header['value']
paragraph = item['paragraph'][0]
text = paragraph['value']

print(module_12)
>>> module-12
print(module_12)
>>> Cycle in Comfort
print(module_12)
>>> This folding exercise bike features a heavily-padded seat and backrest for your comfort
```

Comment: thank you! considering that I may have a maximum of 5 module number with different information, in there a way to extract all those modules and information and to paste this info to other columns once is extracted?

Comment: some information may repeat and I need to extract it and paste in other columns

Comment: I think you should open new question... iam still not quite sure what do you mean